# How to get the job id of the last job run in BigQuery command line tool?

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud, gsutil

I am running some commands in `bq` to extract the data from BigQuery to GCS. I am able to achieve the target result.

I am able to query the data and able to put the data into GCS in desired formats. I was just wondering if there's any possible way to get job id of last job and it's state. I know we can get the all jobs details using `bq` job list methods, but it's giving me an entire result set. I'm just looking to get only the state of that job.

bq --location=US extract --destination_format CSV --compression GZIP dataset_id.table_name gs://bucket_name/table.csv

bq ls -j -n 1

```
jobId          Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration
job_id         extract    FAILURE   30 Mar 13:36:54   0:00:29
```

I want only the last job id and it's state part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want only the last job id and it's state part.

You can pipe it to `awk`:

```
bq ls -j -n 1 | awk '{if(NR>2)print}' | awk '{print $1,$3}'

bquxjob_69ed4f1_169ba1f5665 SUCCESS
```

Comment: Thank you @Graham working perfect. I was looking for table and dataset part,how can we check that table and dataset are present or not in project. does bq tool provide the way to check their availability?

Comment: Note that this works if the job you just ran is the most recent one -- if there's a race condition (e.g. you start a job, someone else or some other process starts a job without you realizing it, and then you run this command), this might not behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference), `bq` offers the global flag `--job_id`, which allows you to set the ID for the job you're launching (in this case, via the `extract` command).  They even have [a section about best practices around generating a job id](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-jobs#generate-jobid).

Once you've created the job, you can get details for that specific job using `bq show --job MY_JOB_ID_HERE`.

If you don't want to have to generate a job ID yourself, a more hacky approach would be to have `bq` print out the API calls using the global `--apilog stdout` option, and you could potentially parse the job ID from that.